# Tensorflow typeError 'feature_columns' with linear classifier

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Im just tying to get some code to work but i keep getting errors.

The code is

```py
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()

classifer = skflow.LinearClassifier(n_classes=3)

classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, classifier.predict(iris.data))

print ("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

but i get this error (latest error after researching and modifying)

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Users\black\Python\machine-learning\MLappIris.py", line 6, in <module>
classifer = skflow.LinearClassifier(n_classes=3)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

- Python: 3.5
- Tensorflow: 1.3.0
- sklearn: 0.18.2
- Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: You should [consult the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearClassifier) to check the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your `feature_columns` - here is the complete script:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()

feature_columns = skflow.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(iris.data)
# WARNING:tensorflow:float64 is not supported by many models, consider casting to float32.

classifier = skflow.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, n_classes=3)

classifier.fit(x=iris.data, y=iris.target, steps=20000)

predictions = list(classifier.predict(iris.data, as_iterable=True))
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, predictions)

print ("Accuracy: %f" % score)
# Accuracy: 0.980000
```

Alternatively, you could also evaluate with a single command, using the `evaluate` method:

```py
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(iris.data, iris.target)["accuracy"]

print ("Accuracy: %f" % accuracy_score)
# Accuracy: 0.980000
```

The warning is due to `iris.data` being `float64` - it doesn't seem to affect anything here, but you could always cast it to `float32`.

The `tf.contrib.learn` [quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/tflearn/), as well as this short [tutorial](https://github.com/karthikmswamy/TFTutorials/blob/master/SkLearn_TensorFlow_Example.ipynb), might be also useful.

Tested with:

- Python 3.5.3
- Tensorflow 1.2.1
- scikit-learn 0.18.1
- Windows 7 (64-bit)